# On multisite setup, currentUser not true in LivePreview

Tags: craft3, multi-site, live-preview

On multisite setup, I have problem to get LivePreview working (Craft 3.3.4). I have one domain live, other not, so it displays Maintenance Page. But I need the editors to edit the entries on that domain and check them in LivePreview.

My templates begin like this:

```
{% if not currentUser %}
  {% include "_main/maintenance_page" %}
{% else %}
  {% include "_main/general_page" %}
{% endif %}
```

It should show the page when the user is logged in. But this doesn't work in LivePreview. Maintenance page is displayed in LP, what is not what I need to achieve.

I have also tried

```
{% if craft.app.request.isLivePreview %}
```

but it returns FALSE for the inactive domain, when tested on LivePreview. So it is not working neither.

Am I missing something? There is no guide in the Docs, afaik.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution to my problem.

```
{% if craft.app.request.isPreview %}
    THIS WILL BE SHOWN IN LIVE PREVIEW,
    even if Your domains are
    www.main-cp-domain.com
    www.second-domain.com
{% else %}
   THIS WILL APPEAR TO ANYONE ON FRONTED
{% endif %}
```

So it does what I need. However, I don't get why craft.app.request.isLivePreview and currentUser are not working in LivePreview, when editing entries for second-domain.com